# Can't get the web OpenLayers plugins to work because of Mac 'Python error'

Tags: python, google-maps, qgis-plugins, google-earth

I'm trying to get a relatively small section of Google satellite/ Google Earth as a layer on QGIS on my Mac. When I go to 'web' and the 'OpenLayers' plugin it just comes up with Python error.

I've already installed Python. I would try uninstalling it and reinstalling it but I can't figure out how. What do I do?

[image]

Comment: The QGIS version of [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2015/20150725_qgis_2.10.1) use the Apple Python version (pre-installed) so you do not need to install another version of Python. What is the error message ?

Comment: I've added a picture of the error box that occurs. I thought that some things had to be installed first. The link I got it off was http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: I'm still having this issue if anyone can help?